# Matplotlib animation duration and why it won't stop

Tags: python, matplotlib

[matplotlib animation duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010586/matplotlib-animation-duration) explained that basically the argument franes in FuncAnimation defines the total amount of frames it should animate. However, when I run the example code it just seems to be running constantly. I expected the fig will stop updating after 4 seconds but it didnot. Is there some kind of loop I need to disable? Thanks. I ran it on Python 3.7 and matplotlib 3.0.3

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2,2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# init func, plot the background of each frame. 
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line, 

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line, 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `repeat=False` in your `FuncAnimation` call.

Checkout the doc please https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

```
repeat : bool, optional

    Controls whether the animation should repeat when the sequence of frames is completed. Defaults to True.
```

Answer (score 0):

As default it repeats animation but you can use

```
FuncAnimation(... , repeat=False)
```

Doc: [FuncAniamtion](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation)